# Is it possible to integrate two Jasper versions in one Java project?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm using a very old Jasper version (0.5.3) in a Java project.
In Jaspersoft Studio 6.x, I can not import the old Jasper reports.
If I wanted to have the old forms in the new Jasper version, I would have to recreate them completely.

Since the old forms work perfectly, I let them continue to run.

Now I want to create a new, complex form in this Java project.
For that I want to use Jaspersoft-Studio 6.x.
But then I have two different Jasper versions in a Java project.

Can I include two Jasper versions in a Java project, or do I have to create a new Java project for the new form?

Comment: For the first part of your question, why don't you just try including both sets of dependencies, and see if you can get a build working?  It would work if your very early version of Jasper Reports used a completely different namespace than the second one.  If not, then perhaps you should consider redoing the earlier report.

Comment: Of course it is possible to use multiple versions of a library in a single Java application - it's just not that easy. If the packages are different you might be able to pull it off by just adding and using them but you might have to use dedicated class loaders for that - that's not a trivial task and quite easy to get wrong. So the better solution might be to provide an application in a different JVM instance that's called by your primary app.

Comment: @SipCat 1) If you have two sets of report's templates (*jrxml*) you can use JasperReports engine 6.x. This version supports old templates. 2) If you have some code based on using JR API 0.5.x it will be better to migrate this code to the latest version of library. 3) You can modify old templates with JSS (studio) and save at old format 4) You can easily migrate old templates just with help of JSS (open and save as) or with help of pair iReport + JSS

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. My previous Jasper-reports have the extensions *.xml and *.jasper.
*.jasper I can not open at all with Jaspersoft Studio 6.2.1. I can open *.xml with Jaspersoft Studio 6.2.1, but only the file will be displayed, but no layout. When I open an xml-file with Jaspersoft Studio 6.x, I can not save the file as jrxml. Open and "save as" does not work. Am I doing something wrong here?